# Spring security configuration using annotation configured beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm attempting to configure spring security to use a service I implemented for authentication.  My services and entity manager and all that are configured with annotations.  I don't want to move all of the service, dao, and entity manager configuration into XML.  How can I get the authentication-provider configuration to reference a service bean that is only configured through annotations?

Here is the configuration in the xml

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

And here is the definition of the service

```
@Configurable
@Service( value = "userService" )
public class UserServiceImpl
        extends BaseDataServiceAbstract<User, Long>
        implements UserService
{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just add this to your XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.package.where.your.beans.are"/>
```

Spring should pick up all your annotation-configured beans and let you autowire them into the security configuration.

**Reference:**

- [Classpath scanning and managed
  components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning)

Comment: thanks for helping a relative spring n00b.  Now that it is finding my beans, it won't find my PersistenceContext, which I'm magically wiring in using 

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

any quick thoughts on that or should I make that a separate question?

Comment: that should usually work automatically. If it doesn't, please make it an extra question and provide some code (the xml context and the bean)

Comment: Thanks again seanizer.  I'll create a new question for that.